# Why a seperate markup identifier for a container and for the fragment?

Tags: wicket

Can I add multiple fragments to a container? Apparently not, but why do I need an seperate markup identifier for the container, and one for the fragment?

In HTML,

```
<div wicket:id="container"></div>
<div wicket:id="container2"></div>

<wicket:fragment wicket:id="myfragment">
    <h3 wicket:id="dexter"></h3>
    <h3 wicket:id="deedee"></h3>
</wicket:fragment>

<wicket:fragment wicket:id="myotherfragment">
    <h3 wicket:id="foo"></h3>
    <h3 wicket:id="bar"></h3>
</wicket:fragment>
```

The web page,

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {

private Component container;
public MyPage() {
    container=new MyFragment("container",this);
    add(container);
    container=new MyOtherFragment("container2",this);
    add(container);
```

One of the fragents is (the other is alike),

```
public MyFragment(String id,WebPage page) {
    super(id,"myfragment",page);
    Label label=new Label("dexter", "Omelette du fromage");
    add(label);
    Label label2=new Label("deedee","That's all you can say!");
    add(label2);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fragments are meant for easy reuse of small components, to fill a dynamic form or similar.
When using fragment you should use a ListView to populate them. That way you can easily build dynamic markup. You need to reference the fragment you want to use and tell wicket where to place it in the markup.

Instead of the two container divs, use a list

```
<div wicket:id="fragmentList">
    <div wicket:id="fragment"></div>
</div>
```

There is no point in having two fragments with the same markup in then (two H3 tags). Instead you can have a header fragment and a label fragment or whatever you need.

```
<wicket:fragment wicket:id="headerFragment">
    <h3 wicket:id="dexter"></h3>
    <h3 wicket:id="deedee"></h3>
</wicket:fragment>

<wicket:fragment wicket:id="labelFragment">
    <label wicket:id="foo"></label>
    <label wicket:id="bar"></label>
</wicket:fragment>

<wicket:fragment wicket:id="inputFragment">
    <label wicket:id="foo"></label>
    <input wicket:id="bar" type="text">
</wicket:fragment>
```

In your WebPage you can add the fragments needed to a list of fragment and add them to a ListView

```
public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) 
{
    List<Fragment> fragments = Arrays.asList(new HeaderFragment("fragment", this), 
                                             new LabelFragment("fragment", this),
                                             new InputFragment("fragment", this));
    add(new ListView<Fragment>("fragmentList", fragments) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Fragment> item) 
    {
       final Fragment frag = _item.getModelObject();
       _item.add((Fragment) frag);
    }           
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a container here. There's the fragment, which has its own id and stands separate from the main markup tree, and there is a place where you can attach your fragment to. This place will have its own id like any other Wicket component.

So the first id in the `Fragment` constructor tells Wicket where to attach the fragment and the second tells it which fragment to attach there.